# How Do I Match Square Bracket As A Literal Character Expression?

Tags: php, regex

I've the following code:

```
<?php

// $content = LOTS OF CONTENT HERE

preg_match('/Token: \'(.*?)\'/', $content, $token);
print_r($token); // Works like a charm.

preg_match_all("/params\['Au' + 'thKey'\] = (.*?);/", $content, $match2);
print_r($match2); // Returns blank array.
```

After checking everything, I came to the solution that there is some problem with escaping. Could anyone help me out? I think its something with square brackets?

PS: The original text to regex is `params['Au' + 'thKey'] = TEXTHERE;`

Comment: can you show us an example text and explain from this text what you want to match exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `+`. You need to escape it to mean a literal `+` like  `\+` or otherwise it would repeat the previous character one or more times.

```
params\['Au' \+ 'thKey'\] = (.*?);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iB3qH6/1)

Code:

```
preg_match_all("~params\['Au' \+ 'thKey'\] = (.*?);~", $content, $match2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
preg_match_all("/params\\['Au' \\+ 'thKey'\\] = (.*?);/", $content, $match2);
```

Comment: You don't need to double-escape those chars.

Comment: Why is that? Double quotes don't un-escape escapes? Or they only un-escape double quotes _and_ escapes?

Comment: I don't trust this language `As in single quoted strings, escaping any other character will result in the backslash being printed too` - But, at least it all parses out correctly.